# Pandas create column based on evaluation of another column with multiple criteria

Tags: pandas, conditional-statements

I would like to create a column of boolean values based on the evaluation of one other column using pandas.  Ideally, I would like to do it with syntax similar to what I've copied, but if that's impossible, I'm open to other suggestions.

df is a pandas dataframe.  AggRow is a column of data with integers.

So, I have data for AggRow that have a range of values.  I can successfully create a new column, conditionmet, based on a single criterion, like so, if I want conditionmet to be True wherever AggRow is less than or equal to 6001:

`conditionmet = df['AggRow'] <= 6001`

But if I want conditionmet to be true if AggRow is <= 6001 or between 10001 and 10009, inclusive, I am having trouble.  The following expression yields conditionmet = True only for the first condition, i.e., where AggRow <= 6001, apparently ignoring what I'm telling it about 10001 and 10009.

`conditionmet = ((df['AggRow'] <= 6001) | ((df['AggRow'] >= 10001) & (df['AggRow'] <= 10009)))`

How do I make conditionmet = True whereever AggRow <= 6001 or AggRow both >= 10001 and <= 10009?  Again, I'd like an answer that uses similar syntax, if possible.  Thank you.

Comment: I've replicated this issue here and this logic `conditionmet = ((df['AggRow'] <= 6001) | ((df['AggRow'] >= 10001) & (df['AggRow'] <= 10009)))` works as expected. Have you tried checking `.dtypes` or some other possibility for why this is not working?

Comment: @joaoavf Thanks for confirming it works for you.  Indeed, the problem was with the data.  AggRow had been populated as the sum of some of its prior values, so where I was expecting aggrow to equal 10002, for example, it did not.

Answer (score 1):

Try using .loc, this will populate the column 'conditionmet' with True where your conditions are met.

```
df.loc[(df['AggRow'] <= 6001)
      |((df['AggRow'] <= 10009)
       &(df['AggRow'] >= 10001)), 'conditionmet'] = 'True'
```

You can also fill the NaN's (aka every record where your conditions above were not met) with 'False' if you desire to:

```
df.fillna('False')
```